# Create a client with Apache cxf, soapUI(or Eclipse) and Fiddler

Tags: eclipse, cxf, soapui, fiddler, wsdl2java

My goal is to create a client to a web service with Apache CXF, located in a host (https://serverOutOfThisWorld) that I could only arrive through a putty tunnel.

```
L8400 -> serverOutOfThisWorld:443
```

I've added in my host the following:

```
 localhost serverOutOfThisWorld
```

So I could put in my browser

```
https://serverOutOfThisWorld:8400/Bus/SomeWebService?wsdl
```

And now, I can reach to this wsdl from a web browser without problem. But this WSDL has some imports that points out to this web, eg:

```
 <xsd:import namespace="http://inter.es/scsp/esquemas/datos" 
        schemaLocation="https://serverOutOfThisWorld/scehma/data.xml"/>
 <xsd:import ....
```

Therefore, the next step is, with Fiddler, trying to map any invocation to serverOutOfThisWorld:433 to my serverOutOfThisWorld:8400. Ok, I created in the Tools/HOSTS options with this:

serverOutOfThisWorld:8400     serverOutOfThisWorld

And, now, I can navigate to this url in a browser:
https://serverOutOfThisWorld/Bus/SomeWebService?wsdl

And, with the proxy defined in SoapUI to make use of Fiddler, I can create a New->Soap Project based in that URL.

But my problem comes when I try to create a client with SoapUI, and Tools>Apache CFX. It seems that the URLs are not override. In The soapUI log, I see:

```
Mon Jun 22 14:07:22 CEST 2015:INFO:command: [cmd.exe, /C, wsdl2java.bat, -p, my.packages, -d, C:\eclipsewks\PruebaWS\src, -client, -exsh, false, -dns, true, -dex, true, -verbose, https://serverOutOfThisWorld:443/Bus/SomeWebService?wsdl]
```

It seems that in cmd/wsdl2Java is not using fiddler...

Other option is trying the same with eclipse.. but at last, eclipse also uses wsd2java for creating the client. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not a direct answer to your question. Let me try to explain what I do when I am in a situation like this.

Instead using proxies and redirections, I simply download all the Wsdl and xsd files to the same directory. After that I update all the import statements with simple file names. Since all the files are in same directory, I just use names in import statements no other path definitions are needed.

If i want to use SoapUI, I just use my version of WSDL and then update endpoint to the real one(In your case this will be fiddler address) if needed.

If i want to generate java client, i just simply use command line with `wsdl2java`. Again, while using this client, I override its connection address accordingly.

Comment: I'm a newbie in wsdl and definitions, and I'm not sure about changing endpoints in the generated clases. Also, with wsd2java in command line and wsdl local, I had a lot of errors (elements-clases with the same name, etc..), although probably it is not related with awsdl lcal/remote thing.  In this point, I'm trying to get close to the WSDL definition on the server.  Also, I can't have a fixed Endpoint, because we hade 3 environment (Test,Pre and Pro), Anyway, thank you for your comment, this would be my last bullet.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to get working this. You have to edit the wsdl2java (.bat or sh) and put the options to get the proxy in Fiddler working:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xmx128M -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888
```

Now I hava other problem (with same classes name), but this is another problem (probably solved with binding names or something).